# Catching Exception with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I want to catch exceptions with pytest.
but I am not getting the actual output.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    x = input("fraction: ") # Accepting string

    print(convert(x))

def convert(x):
    x = x.rpartition("/") # Partitioning 

    try:
        a = x[0]
        b = x[2]

        if b == "0":
            raise ZeroDivisionError

        if not a.isdigit() or not b.isdigit():
            raise ValueError

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return("Zero Division Error")

    except ValueError:
        return("Value Error")

    else:
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
    return(round(a/b))

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

My pytest code:

```
from Test import convert
import pytest


def test_convert1():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        assert convert("a/4")
        
def test_convert():
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
        assert convert("7/0")
```

Here is the output for both test:

```
Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `convert` method catches the exceptions instead of letting them be thrown. If it is supposed to throw those exceptions, then it should not be catching them.

Comment: You capture errors in `convert`, why do you expect them in test? Either check returned value or remove `try/except` block from `convert`. `pytest.raises(E)` is a context manager which is roughly equivalent to `try: do_something(); except E: pass; else: raise AssertionError(...)`

Comment: @khlwooh.
so, how can I write my test_code?

Comment: I can't do away with the try-except

Comment: You cannot confirm in a test that `convert` raises those exceptions because it doesn't raise those exceptions.

Comment: try checking that the return value is "Value Error" instead of checking the exception. that's a bad programming decision, though, fwiw.